# Equations in Word always mangled

Tags: ms-office

I have a document with thousands of equations in Word 16.17.

From times to times these equations display like this

[image]

I scroll up and down and sometimes the equations get fixed.

Is there a way to force the equation redraw on a page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tools-Marco to creat a marco for refresh display.
`Sub RefreshDisplay()
Application.ScreenRefresh
End Sub`
Then use Tools-Customize Keyboard to specify a keyboard shortcut.
[image]