# How to format cases properly in MS Word? I am desperate

Tags: ms-office

I am trying to add a case using the equations of MS Word.

These are two different ways I have tried.

[image]

The first one was obtained by adding a left Curly Brace, then a 3 row by 1 column matrix. I have aligned everything to left, right and center the result is the same.

The second one was obtaining by adding a 3 line case.

Both are incorrectly aligned.

What I want is this, everything beautifully aligned by the operation signs and by the numbers, considering the signs.

[image]

Can this be done in Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Equation Tools tab ,chose liner format and use & to align.
e.g.

`\eqarray(2V_A-5V_C&=-&20@ V_A-6V_B&=-&40@5V_B+6V_C&=&40)`

After you finish edit,change it to pro format,just get what you want.

[image: GIF LINK]

Comment: BRILLIANT! THANKS!!! I may have two other questions for you... [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341585/ms-word-for-mac-how-to-make-all-equations-aligned-to-the-left-of-the-document-a) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341223/equations-in-word-always-mangled) 

Comment: Your method is fantastic but it will fail if one of the equations have a different number of items. For example: suppose the first equation is 200Va + 3700Vb = -2000