# MS Word for Mac: How to make all equations aligned to the left of the document and NON italic by default

Tags: ms-office

I am writing a doc with thousands of equations. Every time I create a new equation it is centered horizontally on the document and the Cambria Math font is italic.

How do I make **by default** all new equations non italic and centered to the left.

I am using MS Word 16.17 for macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the menubar,you can find Format - Equation options.
There are a lot of options to adjust, but there is no italic option.

If you equations are similar or  have something in common.
You can make a template with non italic and centered to the left(e.g just a `=`).
Then save it as a new equation,you can insert your template each time.

Comment: Brilliant and Brilliant. You are an expert in MS Word. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the "Equation" tab, on the left you see the section "Conversions". Open it its dialog box. At the bottom, you see the drop-down menu "Justification". Select "Left"

At the top of the box, you'll find the drop-down menu for the font. Unfortunately, you can select only one type (Cambria Math).